# Linked Lists Homework in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I have to do the following for my homework:

1. Suppose that your linked list is not empty, and is pointed to by the variable head. Write a method called findMin() that goes through the list and finds the least value (you can compare strings just like numbers) and returns that.
2. Suppose that your linked list is not empty, and is pointed to by the variable head. Write a method called getLast() that goes through the list and returns the last thing in the list. This is the value of the last node in the linked list chain.
3. Finish the append method. It runs to the end and attaches the new node to the last existing nodes in the chain. If there are no nodes in the chain yet, it sets self.head to that node. Beware! This is tricky! You might consult your textbook.

I attempted to solve the first one and I am just lost, I don't know if I am messing up the class structure or what (I just learned classes like 3 days ago)

Here's my attempt...

```
 class LinkedList:
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = none
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
def findMin(self):
    currentNode = self.head
    minNode = self.head
    while currentNode != none:
        if currentNode.next < currentNode:
            minNode = currentNode
            currentNode = currentNode.next
    return minNode
```

Comment: Your syntax is fine.  I can see a few issues right off the bat -- e.g. you're comparing Nodes, not `Node.value`, no looping structure (or recursion) in `findMin`, etc.  The problem with this question is that it isn't _specific_.  We don't know _what_ you're having issues with, so that makes it really hard to help in a way that isn't just handing you code (which most people aren't willing to do for a homework assignment)

Comment: Okay I got the looping structure I'm not sure what you mean by the Node.value part, how does this look

Comment: Did you try to run that code? You're accessing `self.head`, but aren't defining it anywhere. (Hint: the assignment reads `the variable head`, not `the variable self.head`) You'll also notice that your program contains an infinite loop.

Comment: So self.head should be assigned instead of self.value? I thought self.head was just a built in function?

Comment: `self.head` is not a built in function. Take a step back, and think about what your `Node` class is supposed to do: It needs to store a value, and it needs to reference the next node in the list. There is no need for a `Node.head` (aka `self.head`) variable. Write some code that creates a short linked list, and then try calling `findMin` on it.

Comment: Okay I could not get the spacing right but I think this is closer,  I'm not really worried about making append/prepend methods because I'm just trying to make a findMin method that would work

Comment: So did you test the `findMin` function?

Comment: Could I do that without appending values to the list?

Comment: Alright I tried it with nothing in the list and it did not crash so that is a good sign right?

Comment: That _is_ a good sign, but it won't work with non-empty lists :) You'll need to add a few values to your list, so you might as well write an `append` function. (Or just do it manually, whichever you prefer.)

Answer (score 1):

As @mgilson mentioned in comments, there are a number of things wrong, and not all were listed.

I think you would benefit a lot from writing (in comments, why not) what you think each line is doing.

Let's start with

```
 currentNode = self.head
```

I think this is trying to say "let's start at the head of the list, by setting currentNode to point to that".

As written, this appears to be accessing a member variable of the current node, called 'head'.  But the Node class definition doesn't have a defined member called head!   And... why do you need to do that?   You are told "the current node *is* the head"!

So you probably mean

```
currentNode = self  # start at the head of the list
```

Next:

```
minNode = self.head
```

This is saying "The node with the current known minimum is stored in this one"

As before, you probably mean:

```
minNode = self # The head currently has the minimum we know about
```

Then:

```
while currentNode != none:
```

First, if you use a syntax highlighting editor, straight away it will tell you that 'None' has  a capital 'N'.

No other problems here.

Then:

```
    if currentNode.next < currentNode:
        minNode = currentNode
        currentNode = currentNode.next
```

This is trying to say "if the value of the next node is less than the value of this one, then the minimum is now ..." ... actually what?   It's saying it's the current one!   But it's not: if this if statement is true, then the *next* one contains the minimum!   And hang on, shouldn't we be comparing with minNode, not currentNode?

Seems like you mean

```
    if currentNode.value < minNode.value:
        minNode = currentNode    # this node is now the smallest we know about
```

and this next line needs to be outside the if loop, because it moves us on to the next node:

```
    currentNode = currentNode.next  # move on to the next node
```

Phew, nearly there: now we have to return the minimum *value* not, the node that has the minimum value (read the instructions carefullly.

```
 return minNode.value
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's do this homework!

Let `Node` be a list cell. It has two fields `value` and `next` (also called `car/cdr` or `head/tail` in functional languages).

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
```

`append(node, other)` can be defined as follows: if `node` has no "next" node (i.e. it is the last), attach `other` right to this `node`. Otherwise, take the "next" node, and append (recursively) `other` to that one:

```
    def append(self, other):
        if self.next:
            self.next.append(other)
        else:
            self.next = other
```

Now let's define two essential functionals: `map` and `reduce`. `map` applies a function to each node in order and returns the list of results:

```
    def map(self, fn):
        r = [fn(self.value)]
        if self.next:
            r += self.next.map(fn)
        return r
```

`reduce` applies a function to each node and combines results into a single value:

```
    def reduce(self, fn, r=None):
        if r is None:
            r = self.value 
        else:
            r = fn(r, self.value)
        if self.next:
            return self.next.reduce(fn, r)
        return r
```

Now you're ready for the homework.

Create a list:

```
lst = Node(1)
lst.append(Node(8))
lst.append(Node(3))
lst.append(Node(7))
```

print all values:

```
print lst.map(lambda x: x)
```

find the last value:

```
print lst.reduce(lambda r, x: x)
```

find the max value:

```
print lst.reduce(max)
```

etc

Let us know if you have questions.

Comment: Don't you think you overdid it a little? OP is new to this, and I doubt he has any use for a `map`and `reduce` function.

Comment: @Rawing: yes, my post is intentionally a bit too advanced to the OP's level. If they're serious about learning programming, they will ask questions and try to understand it (that's really not that complicated). If they are not, there's no point in giving them an immediate copy-paste solution.

Comment: It strikes me that the OP is like a learner trying to play chess against a computer and asking us why he can't get any of his back row pieces to move out when he hasn't moved any pawns yet.  I'm not *sure*, but I think that extra class LinkedList line he added at the top is showing us that he has an "empty linked list that he is working with". In this context, this generously detailed answer discussing intricate openings and endgame tactics appears to be an order of magnitude out of reach.

Comment: @GreenAsJade: From my understanding, Stackoverflow is a database of programming solutions, not a "people helping people" forum. Even if the OP doesn't understand or doesn't want to understand my answer yet (as I said that depends on their attidude), still it might be helpful for someone else with the same problem. As for the pedagogical value, people should be taught to do things in a nice and clean way right from the beginning. Back to your chess example, if you show the very first move to someone, let it be `e4`, not `f3`.

Comment: I think it is a generous answer. However, the OP's problem is not that they don't know how to do a linked list. It's that they don't know how to write python that works, at all. It strikes me that there is tension between the "title", which refers to "Linked Lists In Python" (which this answer deals with) and the actual question, which was "what is wrong with my class?". I believe this answer is very useful for someone who comes searching for "Linked List in Python". I don't think it's at all useful for the OP to deal with "what is wrong with my class". The downvote was mine, I removed it.

Comment: (That is to say, if you edit the answer, I will be able to remove it! - 2 hours have passed, it's locked ATM)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: don't worry, and thanks for interesting comments!